# Run Javascript function before jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to be able to get my form to check if the 2 input boxes have any data input into them before it submits. The reason I am having trouble with this is because I am using the following -

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        method = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
    })
    this.reset();
    return false;
});
```

This makes it so the form is submitted without the page having to refresh, I also have an image appear for a few seconds when the submit button has been pressed -

```
$(".bplGame1Fade").click(function(){
$("#bplGame1ThumbUp").fadeIn(1000);
$("#bplGame1ThumbUp").fadeOut(1000); });
```

I don't want these to run unless both the input boxes have data in them. I have tried using OnClick() and OnSubmit(). When using these the message appears saying it isn't a valid entry as I want but once you click OK the form continues to submit.

Is there anyway I can run a JS function to check the input boxes and if one of the boxes is empty, cancel the submission.

Any help with this would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: So why don't you check it before the ajax request? did i miss something?

Comment: I do, but the ajax request continues anyway. I should point that I am a beginner at this and got the jQuery code from an online source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just add an if condition to check if you ever get an empty input? You can return the function if it's not valid.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        method = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    var context = this;
    var valid = true;
    var total = that.find('[name]').length;
    that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        if (!value) {
            valid = false;
            return;
        }
        data[name] = value;
        if (index === total - 1) { //last item
            if (valid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: method,
                    data: data,
                });
                context.reset();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: You could put the ajax call inside of the foreach. So on the last item, you would make the ajax call if every input had a value.